# Trying to create linked list in C. But only half the requested nodes are created

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a program that creates a linked list with nodes made up of 2 integers. It asks for the number of nodes.

If I input an even number of nodes, the program only creates half of them but if I input an odd number, then it crashes after half of the nodes.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{

    int student;
    int exam;
    struct node *link;
};

int main(void){

    int student_num, exam_num, node_num, i;
    struct node *start;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *temp;

    printf("How many nodes?: ");
    scanf("%d",&node_num);


    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    start = temp;

    start->link = NULL;

    next = start;

    //Creates node_num nodes
    for(i=1;i<=node_num;i++){

        temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        next->link=temp;

        next=temp;
        next->link=NULL;
    }

    next=start->link;

    //Fills in the numbers
    for(temp=start;temp->link!=NULL;temp=next->link){

        printf("\nStudent number: ");
        scanf("%d",&student_num);

        temp->student=student_num;

        printf("Exam number: ");
        scanf("%d",&exam_num);

        temp->exam=exam_num;

        next=temp->link;
    }

    next=start->link;

    //Shows the result
    for(temp=start;temp->link!=NULL;temp=next->link){

        printf("\nStudent number: %d\tExam number: %d\n",temp->student,temp->exam);
        next=temp->link;
    }
}
```

Comment: Step through the code in your debugger, and see when the variables go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to the next node in the list twice. You do it in the `for()` loop header:

```
for(temp=start;temp->link!=NULL;temp=next->link){
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and also at the bottom of the loop:

```
    next=temp->link;
```

Just do one or the other, not both. Change the header to:

```
for(temp=start;temp->link!=NULL;temp=temp->link){
```

and get rid of the line at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected your program. You were trying to create n+1 nodes and iterating in wrong way. Just use one variable from start and stop till you reach NULL value. Let me know if you din't understand any part of it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{

    int student;
    int exam;
    struct node *link;
};

int main(void){

    int student_num, exam_num, node_num, i;
    struct node *start;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *temp;

    printf("How many nodes?: ");
    scanf("%d",&node_num);

    if(node_num == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    start = temp;

    start->link = NULL;

    next = start;

    //Creates node_num nodes
    for(i=1;i<node_num;i++){

        temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        next->link=temp;

        next=temp;
        next->link=NULL;
    }

    //Fills in the numbers
    for(temp=start;temp!=NULL;temp=temp->link){

        printf("\nStudent number: ");
        scanf("%d",&student_num);

        temp->student=student_num;

        printf("Exam number: ");
        scanf("%d",&exam_num);

        temp->exam=exam_num;

    }

    //Shows the result
    for(temp=start;temp!=NULL;temp=temp->link){

        printf("\nStudent number: %d\tExam number: %d\n",temp->student,temp->exam);
    }

}
```